# Passing data on prepareForSegue for a Popover Segue: strange behavior in iOS 5

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, uipopovercontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I noticed some strange behavior when passing data to a popover in iOS 5. The Popovers `viewDidLoad` method is called before `prepareForSegue` is called:

In Storyboard a segue connects a button of `FirstViewController` to `PopoverViewController`, which is embedded in a Navigation Controller.

For testing the two methods are logged:

```
/* FirstViewController.m */
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPopover"]) {
        NSLog(@"FirstViewController: prepareForSegue");
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        PopoverViewController *popoverVC = (PopoverViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        popoverVC.myProperty = @"Data to be passed";
    }
}
```

and in the other ViewController:

```
/* PopoverViewController.m */
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"PopoverViewController: viewDidLoad");
}
```

Under iOS 6 the behavior is as expected:

```
2013-02-25 09:03:53.747 FirstViewController: prepareForSegue
2013-02-25 09:03:53.751 PopoverViewController: viewDidLoad
```

Under iOS 5 `viewDidLoad` of the `PopoverViewController` is called before `prepareForSegue`:

```
2013-02-25 09:05:28.723 PopoverViewController: viewDidLoad
2013-02-25 09:05:28.726 FirstViewController: prepareForSegue
```

This is strange and makes it hard to pass data to the Popover which can be used in `viewDidLoad`. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: The solution is: you have to set a property, and only then use that in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem now using the `viewWillAppear:` method instead of `viewDidLoad`. I think this is the better method for configuring views anyway (as the view could be already loaded and the view should be configured on every appear).

The `viewWillAppear:` method is loaded after the `prepareForSegue` in iOS 5 and iOS 6.

However, for those needing `viewDidLoad` the solution suggested by tkanzakic is the one that works then.

Comment: FYI: viewWillAppear may be called multiple times. One example is when a model VC is presented above the VC and dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom setter for your property and perform the operations you need from there, I use to do it in this way:

```
- (void)setCity:(GLQCity *)city    
{
    if (_city != city) {
        _city = city;

        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.city) {
        ...
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    [self configureView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the differences between iOS 5 and 6, but I had run into similar confusions in the past.  If you follow the general rules of thumb:

1. prepareForSegue is called before destination VC's viewDidLoad
2. viewDidLoad is called only after ALL outlets are loaded
3. Therefore, do not attempt to reference any destination VC's outlets in source VC's prepareForSegue.

Then, you would naturally arrived at either solutions - implement viewDidAppear vs. viewDidLoad, or set destination VC's properties only vs. touching any of its outlets.

Another lesson learned with regards to prepareForSegue is to avoid redundant processing. For example, if you already segue a tableView cell to a VC via storyboard, you could run into similar race condition if you attempt to process BOTH tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue.  One can avoid such by either utilizing manual segue or forgo any processing at didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Re: tableView:didselectRow I've run into this before. Good tip!